# How do I make a macro that calls a block with arbitrary arguments?

Tags: objective-c, macros, c-preprocessor, objective-c-blocks

I'm trying to write a macro that expands into a safe way to call a block.

```
#define callBlockSafely(blockName, args...) \
if (blockName)                              \
{                                           \
    blockName(##args);                      \
}
```

However, when I try to use this, I get this error:

[image: "Pasting formed '(1', an invalid preprocessing token"]

So, what are alternative ways of achieving this?

Comment: Define a *method* instead and use that one!

Comment: Why do you think you need to use `try/catch`? You should fix that problem.

Comment: @rmaddy This is one of two macros; the other doesn't have the try-catch. I suppose that's excessive for this example; I'll pare it down.

Comment: It also eliminates the need for a macro.

Comment: @rmaddy Could you elaborate?

Comment: What's the point of a macro just to eliminate the `if`? Instead of `callBlockSafely(callback, 1, nil)` you just need `if (callback) callback(1);`. Do you really think the macro saves anything now?

Comment: @rmaddy Our coding standards require every `if` to be on its own line, followed by a `{` on its own line, followed by the contents, followed by a `}` on its own line. I don't like this since it makes line counts higher than they need to be, and this is one way of reducing that. And again, a sister macro will have the try-catch with naught but a few characters difference in the name

Comment: Even with your coding standard, there is no point for a macro just to avoid having to type the `if { ... }`.